# Assign Task to a parent (User Story) in TFS via excel

Tags: excel, tfs

I imported a TFS query to excel to add a bunch of tasks. That part worked well. Now I just need to attach them all to their appropriate user stories (parent). I tried a bunch of different options in "column options", but none of them let me choose the task's parent. Is this even possible through excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve that by adding parent/child linked backlog items and tasks, please see [Bulk add or modify work items with Excel](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/office/bulk-add-modify-work-items-excel) for details.

In you case, you have bulk added the tasks to project,you need to link parent user stories by following below steps:

1. Select any task and link it to its' parent story (to generate the tree level title in query).
2. Create a **Tree of Work items** query like this:
   [image]
3. Open Excel,**New list** > Select the created query above > **OK**
4. Edit the query in excel, move the Tasks title from **Title1** to
   **Title2** accordingly based on their appropriate user stories.
5. Click **Publish**, check the Parent link in backlog.
   [image]